# Calling a method which throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, methods, filenotfoundexception, throws

I'm pretty sure this is an easy one but I could not find a straight forward answer. How do I call a method with a `throws FileNotFoundException`?

Here's my method:

```
private static void fallingBlocks() throws FileNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You call it, and either declare that *your* method throws it too, or catch it:

```
public void foo() throws FileNotFoundException // Or e.g. throws IOException
{
    // Do stuff
    fallingBlocks();
}
```

Or:

```
public void foo()
{
    // Do stuff
    try
    {
        fallingBlocks();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // Handle the exception
    }
}
```

See [section 11.2 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/exceptions.html#11.2) or the [Java Tutorial on Exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more details.

Comment: Hi Jon Skeet, Is there any other way through which i can achieve the same ?

Comment: @MadhuAvinash: No, you either have to catch the exception or declare that your method might throw it. That's just the way it is.

Answer (score 3):

You just call it as you would call any other method, and make sure that you either

1. catch and handle `FileNotFoundException` in the calling method;
2. make sure that the calling method has `FileNotFoundException` or a superclass thereof on its `throws` list.

Answer (score 3):

You simply `catch` the Exception or rethrow it. Read about [exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I get your question, just call the method:

```
try {
    fallingBlocks();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    /* handle */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it like calling a normal method. The only difference is you have to handle the exception either by surrounding it in try..catch or by throwing the same exception from the caller method.

```
try {
    // --- some logic
    fallingBlocks();
    // --- some other logic
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // --- exception handling
}
```

or

```
public void myMethod() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // --- some logic
    fallingBlocks();
    // --- some other logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You call it like any other method too. However the method might fail. In this case the method throws the exception. This exception should be caught with a try-catch statement as it interrupts your program flow.